# Min of two dates in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two cells in OpenOffice Calc (A1 and B1). In cell A1, I have "2014/01/01" and in cell B1, I have "2014/06/03". I want to find the minimum/smallest of the values in A1 and B1. I actually have hundreds of values in column A and column B and I want to populate column C with the smallest of the two dates in column A and B.

I tried entering the following into column C1:

```
=MIN(A1,B1)
```

which I thought would produce "2014/01/01", but instead it initially produced "0". I then tried right-clicking on cell C1 and I did format cell and changed the format to "Date" which then produced "12/30/99" which is also incorrect.

I've tried googling on this question, but I haven't been able to figure out why the MIN function doesn't work with dates. Is there a different open office function that I should be using to find the smallest of two dates? Or something wrong with my MIN expression?

Comment: I don't have OpenOffice, but I tried this in LibreOffice Calc, which is a descendent.  It looks like the issue might be that your dates are being interpreted as text.  When I entered the dates as you show them, they were automatically reformatted to 2014-01-01 and 2014-06-03, and the min function worked.

Comment: @fixer1234, the date format was the problem, when I changed the input date format from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/dd/YYYY it fixed the problem.

Comment: For the benefit of others with the same problem, could you put your solution in the form of an answer? (You are allowed to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function SMALL ([documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/small.php)).

=small(A1:B1;1)

This return first/oldest (1 as second parameter in brackets) date in array.

Comment: when I pasted your small function into openoffice calc, it returned "#VALUE!"

Comment: And you have set right date format? I dont have OpenOffice, but Office and for me it's working and your date format convert to my. Check format of columns.